# Are we able to search or fetch with HIGHESTMODSEQ In yahoo server?

Tags: imap, yahoo

Hi I tried following IMAP commands in Gmail, It is working where as in yahoo not working.

```
A UID FETCH *:* (UID) (MODSEQ) 
A BAD [CLIENTBUG] UID FETCH Additional arguments found after last expected argument
```

In gmail i am getting MODSEQ as one of the response.

FYI:

In gmail CONDSTORE is one of available capability whereas in yahoo it is not. But still yahoo providing HIGHESTMODSEQ for every SELECT/EXAMINE. if it is maintaining HIGHESTMODSEQ then there is a way to get for per-message basis. please tell me how to archive this in Yahoo....
Thanks...

Comment: There isn't. Yahoo implements a subset of CONDSTORE, namely, per folder sequences. It allows a small optimization where you can skip synchronizing a folder if the sequence hasn't changed. Per message sequences are not available unfortunately. This is why CONDSTORE is not in the capability list. It's a custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

When the server tells you there's a CLIENTBUG, it is usually right. The syntax for FETCH is on page 85 of RFC 3501. Read it. In this case, the correct version is:

```
A UID FETCH *:* (UID MODSEQ)
```

You could also make the list simpler, since UID implies UID and *:* means "from * to *":

```
A UID FETCH * (MODSEQ)
```

Or turn the single-item list into a single item:

```
A UID FETCH * MODSEQ
```

Comment: Perhaps. I hope not. Didn't he speak of thousands of users and one node.js process?

Comment: Yahoo doesn't do CONDSTORE. They really don't support MODSEQ in UID FETCH.